# All permutations in range with parameters

Tags: algorithm, permutation, combinatorics

I am trying to find efficient algorithm to solve the following problem.
Give a range of numbers from 1..N, and some arbitrary numbers K and M, find all possible permutation in given range. Where K represents the number of elements and M represents a minimum distance between elements.

So let's look at the example:

```
array = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
K = 2
M = 2
```

so the output then will be

```
(3,5)
(3,6)
(4,6)
```

so you can see how complexity increases if K and M getting bigger.

Cheers.

Comment: in your example the min dist' is 2 and |6-3| = 3 , is this right?

Comment: Yes, the min distance is 2 but it could be more between elements. Mainly that it cannot be less than min distance.

Comment: When you say "efficient algorithm", it means time linear? Is memory a problem? Although you used an array, is the range always complete and ordered?

Comment: can you give another example ..

Comment: Sorry, I should express more clearly. No memory is not a problem and yes sequence is always sorted, I have currently solved with approx O(n3)

Comment: Another example is, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 with M = 2 and K = 3, Output (3,5,7) (4,6,8)(3,6,8) ...

Comment: Those aren't permutations, those are subsets. For permutations order matters. E.g. (1,2,3), (3,2,1), (1,3,2), (2,1,3)...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is equivalent to finding subsets (combinations) of size `k` from set with `n - (k-1)*(m-1)` elements. Number of these is `(n - (k-1)*(m-1) choose k)`.

In original problem, when first element is selected, e.g. 2, than `m-1` elements after it can't be part of result set because of distance restriction. That hold for all result element except largest one.

So for combination of `n - (k-1)*(m-1)`, `(c_0, c_1, ..., c_{k-1})` corresponding combination in original problem is `(c_i + i*(k-1), i=0, ..., k-1)`.